# How to set focus to the old window on button click in PyQt5 Python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyautogui

My Current Project is to create a On Screen Keyboard for my personal usage with my personal functionality. I made gui and primary function in PyQt5 with Python. I managed to type the letter on button click with `pyautogui.write()` method. But the problem is, where I want to type there is no focus. suppose I want to write on chrome's address bar or any other input field on my monitor. when I click on button to type a letter, chrome lost focus. I want to set focus to the old window while press on any button. I searched on google about this but didn't found any answer. How can i set focus to old window? or is there any better way to type on focus lost state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to "set the focus back", as it would be almost impossible to know what window had the focus before (and a new window might raise in the meantime). What you should actually do is to *prevent* your window to get focus at all, thus avoiding it to steal focus from the others.

In order to achieve this, you must set the appropriate window [flag](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) (or initialize the widget with it using the `flags` keyword argument), which for this is `Qt.WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus`.
Note that you might also want to set the `Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` in order to always keep your window above the others:

```py
class MyKeyboard(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(
            QtCore.Qt.WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus
            | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        )
```